# Problems creating a Function to make a table out of JSON data contained in a VARiable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to learn how to create a Javascript function, in order to create a table in HTML with some data extracted from a JSON file.
I would love to get some light ...

I created a JS file, storing the JSON data into a Variable at it shows partially here :

```js
var data = {
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":" Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "congress": "113",
         "chamber": "Senate",       
         "num_results": 105,
         "offset": 0,
         "members": [
              {
                 "id": "A000360",
                 "title": "Senator, 2nd Class",
                 
                 "first_name": "Lamar",
                 "party": "R",
                 "leadership_role": null,
                 "twitter_account": "SenAlexander",
                 "seniority": "11",
                 "phone": null,
                 "fax": null,
                 "state": "TN",
                 "votes_with_party_pct": 85.97
               },
                           {
                 "id": "A000368",
                 "title": "Senator, 3rd Class",
                 "first_name": "Kelly",
                 "party": "R",
```

I created the HTML file with a  element, and a  inside, where I intend to insert the table.

```html
<table>
           <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Party</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Years in Office</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="senate-data">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And now I am trying to create the right JS function that fills the table. But I am quite lost guessing which Variables should I create and how to extract the needed elements ("first_name","party", "state" and "seniority").
What I have done so far is

```js
function createTable() {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("senate-data"); //to reference the tbody element 
    
    
    for (var i = 0; j < data.results[0].members.length; i++) {// to loop over the whole members array
        var row = document.createElement("tr"); //to create the tr element
        
        for (var j = 0; j < data.results[0].members.length; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td")//to create the table cells
            var cellText = document.createTextNode() //to create the text content of the cells
            cell.appendChild(cellTex);//to add the text to the TD
            row.appendChild(cell)//to add the TD to the TR
        }
     
        }   
    tbody.appendChild(row)//to add the row to the tbody
    }
```

but I don´t know how to include in the function how to find the "party", "seniority" etc... fields I need, and how to include them in every TD element.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```js
const data = { "status": "OK", "copyright": " Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.", "results": [{ "congress": "113", "chamber": "Senate", "num_results": 105, "offset": 0, "members": [{ "id": "A000360", "title": "Senator, 2nd Class", "first_name": "Lamar", "party": "R", "leadership_role": null, "twitter_account": "SenAlexander", "seniority": "11", "phone": null, "fax": null, "state": "TN", "votes_with_party_pct": 85.97 }] }] };

const createTable = (tbody, data, fields) => {  
  for (const elem of data) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    
    for (const field of fields) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");        
      row.appendChild(cell);
      cell.innerText = elem[field];
    }    
  }
};

createTable(
  document.getElementById("senate-data"), data.results[0].members, 
  ["first_name", "party", "state", "seniority"]
);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Party</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Years in Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="senate-data">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Remarks about your code:

1. In the following line, `j` does not exist (you probably meant `i`).

   ```
   var i = 0; j < data.results[0].members.length; i++)
   ```
2. Consider removing redundant comments that echo what the code clearly does such as:

   ```
   document.createElement("tr"); //to create the tr element
   ```
3. `tbody.appendChild(row)` is out of place (it should be inside the `i` loop--the inaccurate indentation of braces may have caused confusion).
4. The outer loop correctly attempts to iterate over the rows, but the inner loop should loop over the fields (columns, cells, whatever) you're interested in creating rather than also iterating over the rows.
5. Avoid using global variables; use parameters instead. The function should be a black box that won't be broken when something in the outer scope changes.
6. Try to make the function general and reusable by using parameters and letting the caller handle specifics about the data and table element.

---

Backward-compatible version:

```js
var data = { "status": "OK", "copyright": " Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.", "results": [{ "congress": "113", "chamber": "Senate", "num_results": 105, "offset": 0, "members": [{ "id": "A000360", "title": "Senator, 2nd Class", "first_name": "Lamar", "party": "R", "leadership_role": null, "twitter_account": "SenAlexander", "seniority": "11", "phone": null, "fax": null, "state": "TN", "votes_with_party_pct": 85.97 }] }]};

function createTable(tbody, data, fields) {  
  data.forEach(function (elem) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    
    fields.forEach(function (field) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      row.appendChild(cell);
      cell.innerText = elem[field];
    });
  });
}

createTable(
  document.getElementById("senate-data"), data.results[0].members, 
  ["first_name", "party", "state", "seniority"]
);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Party</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Years in Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="senate-data">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Classic `for` loop version (not recommended; more error-prone and harder on the eyes):

```js
var data = { "status": "OK", "copyright": " Copyright (c) 2019 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.", "results": [{ "congress": "113", "chamber": "Senate", "num_results": 105, "offset": 0, "members": [{ "id": "A000360", "title": "Senator, 2nd Class", "first_name": "Lamar", "party": "R", "leadership_role": null, "twitter_account": "SenAlexander", "seniority": "11", "phone": null, "fax": null, "state": "TN", "votes_with_party_pct": 85.97 }] }]};

function createTable(tbody, data, fields) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    
    for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      row.appendChild(cell);
      cell.innerText = data[i][fields[j]];
    }
  }
}

createTable(
  document.getElementById("senate-data"), data.results[0].members, 
  ["first_name", "party", "state", "seniority"]
);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Party</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Years in Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="senate-data">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: FIrst of all thanks for taking your time. 
I tried it, but gives me a Parsing error: "The keyword 'const# is reserved  const data = { "

But anyway, since , for now, have just "studied" the , if functions, for loops, with variables, arrays and strings ..I was hoping to make the funtion with those elements, since I still haven't read and practiced about CONST variables ..

Comment: You can change all `const` to `var` if you're on an old version of JS, along with a few other things. Hopefully my update helps with backward compatibility.

Comment: Forget what I wrote! It worked (i had an old Script on the html i forgot to delete)
But I would really like to know how could I make it those "for (var elem of data) " loops into "older" for lops (i=0, i<data.results.....etc)"  as I was trying , since I would love to fully understand what I was doing wrong.

Thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: Look at the snippet I added to the bottom.

Comment: thanks again! you were quicker replying than I was editing  ...with your previous version worked (i guess with this one too). But my intention still stands: how would it looked like with the function I was trying to write??
although old JS, and longer code, I thought I was on the right direccion ... and I would like to know what I was missing ... because I though it was a question of adding the right Variables 
But anyway you have done more than enough....

Comment: OK--I added a "classic" version at the bottom. Let me know if this doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: wow ...that is just great. 
I see I was not that faaar away from the solution, although I miss a lot of concepts still.

May I ask you what is the big difference between my "data.results[0].members.length" to loop over the "members" array.
And your "data.length;" and "fields.length" ?

Comment: Well, functions should not have hard-coded things like `data.results[0].members` because this restricts the function down to very specific input. When you want to create a table with a different set of data, you'd have to throw this whole function out. But if you write it in a general way from the outset, your code automatically grows to handle arbitrary tables. This is why I make the caller do the `data.results[0].members` business; the function expects an array of objects. You can see all the hard-coded strings are in the parameter list and the function "just works" based on these knobs.

Comment: I see, it is a matter of good coding practice ...
I was supposed to be able to solve this table with the things I have studied so far, that is why I guess my code is too "raw" .

Comment: sure, just ask.

Comment: In orden to learn my lesson, need clarification (or where to look for it) about

- the use of "data" and "field" : are they attributes from JS objects , or where are defined?

-the way you insert the text in the cell through innerText : I do not get the = data[i][fields[j]] (specially the doble [] in fields).  How could I make it "easier" (alas worse code)

And finally, the way you call the function, other way , maybe decomposing that parameters into more lines, of calling it, closer to my (tiny) level of knowleage? Dunoo If I am even making sense...too many hours with this..

Comment: Have you looked at parameters to functions yet? If not, look them up. I just made those up: `data` is an array of objects, and `fields` are all the properties we want to pull out of each object to populate a row of cells. You can remove these parameters and replace them with the hard-coded `document.getElementById("senate-data"), data.results[0].members, 
  ["first_name", "party", "state", "seniority"]` if that helps make sense of what's going on. Or, try writing your own data and fields and try the function out on those.

Comment: As for `= data[i][fields[j]]`, well, `data` is an array of objects, so we're indexing into the `i`-th object. After we get `data[i]`, we access the `j`-th field, which is some string like `"first_name"` or `"seniority"`. Replacing the variables with example literals would look like, say, `data[0]["seniority"]`. The outer loop accesses rows and the inner loop accesses fields/cells/columns (however you want to think about them is fine). Use `console.log(i, j, data[i], fields[j], data[i][fields[j]]);` to get a sense of what is what.

Comment: perfectly explained. I will do some tests as you suggest, to get a deeper understanding.

Las question would be :
may I hire you as my private teacher?? :D  ....I really appreciate your help and patience .

...seriously ...how much per hour? XD

Comment: Sure--I have contact info at the website linked in my profile, but you'll need a [brainfuck interpreter](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) to de-obfuscate the email address that's posted there.